# Manage DB before uploading to playstore in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have uploaded an application to play store couple of weeks back. This application involves sqlite database that stores information on username, password, other details that given are by user while using the application locally.

Now I have couple of more tables and fields added to database and wanna upload the application to playstore as an update?

My worry is if the user updates the application from playstore - After update - all the data stored in database will be saved or will the user has to recreate everything from scratch?

Let me know!

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to override the onUpgade method of SQLiteOpenHelper. In the OnUpgrade method you can either erase the data(drop sqlite command) or maintain the data with the additional columns(alter sqlite command) or create new table (create sqlite command).

Refer the following snippet.

I assume your version would be 1.(Plz check the constructor of your SqliteOpenHelper class)

Increment the version by 1.

```
class DatabaseHelper extends SqliteOplenHelper{

        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;   //new version of the database
        private static final int Database_name = "MyDatabase";
        private static final String alterUserName = "alter table users add name text";
        private static final String table_users = "create table if not exists "
            + users + "(" + "_id integer primary key autoincrement,"
            + "email text" + ")";

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, Database_name, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        cntxt = context;
    }

        @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL(table_users);
        db.execSQL(alterUserName);

    }
}
```

Now everytime when you roll the next update with database changes be sure to increment the database version by 1 else let it remain the same.

Comment: It gave my force close when I upgraded the application. I did clean installation things were fine. Looks like I have to do like what you told mentioned Aditya. Let me try it out and get back!

Comment: I am getting force close when I set:

db.execSQL(Table_Users); says: 

(1) near "Table_Users": (code 1): , while compiling: UsersTable

Comment: @TheDevMan Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't done for you automatically. In your SQLiteOpenHelper, you need to increment the Schema integer. This will trigger the on upgrade method for your existing users.

Adding a table is not a problem, just do this in onUpgrade, nothing breaks.

However to add fields, you should use the 'ALTER TABLE' SQL command

> If you add new columns you can use ALTER TABLE to insert them into a live table. If you rename or remove columns you can use ALTER TABLE to rename the old table, then create the new table and then populate the new table with the contents of the old tab

See the official reference [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29)